# An inequality of a complex polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, polynomials

> Let $$P(z)=c_nz^n+...+c_1z+c_0$$ be a polynomial with complex
> coefficients, where $c_n\neq 0$. For each $r>0$, define
> $$M(r):=\sup_{|z|=r}|P(z)|.$$ Prove that for any $K>1$, the following
> inequlity holds $$M(Kr)\le K^nM(r).$$

I believe a proper use of the Hadamard’s three-circles theorem will solve it, but I couldn't find the right annulus(the right choice of $r_1$, $r_2$ and $t$ in the theorem). Also I tried to use induction on $n$ but again didn't get nowhere. I also tried to calculate it by using triangle inequality:

\begin{align*}
        M(Kr)&=\sup_{|z|=Kr}|c_nz^n+...+c_1z+c_0|\\
        &\le |c_n||K|^n|r|^n+...+|c_1||K||r|+|c_0|\\
        &< K^n(|c_n||r|^n+...+|c_1||r|+|c_0|)\\
\end{align*}

But then I don't know where to go from there. So I'm curious about the solution to this problem.

Any comment or hint are appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you need a big theorem here. Have you tried just writing down the formula for $P(Kz)$ for $K>1$ and then estimating the size using the triangle inequality? I haven't worked out the details, but I am confident this will work

Comment: @SamBallas I actually did try this before, and I got $M(Kr)\le K^n(|c_n||r|^n+...+|c_1||r|+|c_0|)$. But I was not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Prove it directly with $Q(z)=P(z)/z^n$.

Comment: @SamBallas I added my calculation to the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(I'll use the notation $M(r, f) = \sup_{|z|=r}|f(z)|$ for holomorphic functions $f$.)

Consider the polynomial
$$
 Q(z) = c_0 z^n+c_1 z^{n-1} + \cdots +c_{n-1} z+c_n \, .
$$
For all $z \ne 0$ is $P(z) = z^n Q(1/z)$, and therefore
$$
 M(\rho, P) = \rho^n M(\frac{1}{\rho}, Q)
$$
for all $\rho > 0$. Since $M( \cdot, Q)$ is an increasing function (by the maximum modulus theorem) it follows that
$$
 M(Kr, P) = K^nr^n M(\frac{1}{Kr}, Q) \le K^nr^n M(\frac{1}{r}, Q)
= K^n M(r, P)
$$
for $K > 1$.